# Why does ajaxForm submit form in IE7/8 without AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I'm pretty new to ajax, so I'm surprised that this doesn't work or error for me in IE7/8. Works in other browsers though. This is a validation script that validates form content and then submits a form. On success, it updates the page:

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script> 
<script> 
    google.load("jquery", "1.6.2");
</script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.form.js"></script>
```

[within a document ready function]

```
// prepare the form when the DOM is ready 
if ($("#contact_form").exists()){
    $("#contact_form").validate();

    // bind form using ajaxForm 
    $("#contact_form").ajaxForm({ 

        beforeSubmit:function() {
           return $("#contact_form").valid()
        },

        // target identifies the element(s) to update with the server response 
        target: "#success", 

        // success identifies the function to invoke when the server response 
        // has been received; here we apply a fade-in effect to the new content 
        success: function() { 
            $(".form-fields").hide();
            $("#success").fadeIn("slow"); 
        } 
    }); 
}
```

Thanks in advance! It does submit the form, but doesn't use ajax or do any error validation.

Comment: From "doesn't use ajax or do any validation" I suspect the `if` in the post is 1) never being encountered (perhaps because of other code) or; 2) `exists` is returning a false-value.

Comment: nope - killing that conditional doesn't help... I added an alert("testing") to the beforeSubmit function, which ran.

Comment: This might solve the problem, its answer to a previous question -- > [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918474/div-content-loaded-via-ajax-doesnt-appear-in-ie/6943757#6943757)

Comment: I don't think so. the submit function is a complete path. I am seeing content replace the form in the way of the success div... it just isn't validating...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turns out it was this issue: [jQuery Validation not working in IE7 + IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5942327/jquery-validation-not-working-in-ie7-ie8/5942500#5942500)

Had to revert back to jquery 1.5.2. who knew??